# Flutter unable to switch from master to dev channel

Tags: flutter

I'm on the `master` channel, and want to switch to the `dev`. When I run

```dart
flutter channel dev
```

It gives me a nice error:

```
git: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
git:    dev/automated_tests/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/benchmarks/complex_layout/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/benchmarks/macrobenchmarks/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/benchmarks/metrics_center/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/benchmarks/microbenchmarks/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/benchmarks/platform_views_layout/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/benchmarks/platform_views_layout_hybrid_composition/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/benchmarks/test_apps/stocks/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/bots/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/devicelab/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/android_semantics_testing/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/android_splash_screens/splash_screen_kitchen_sink/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/android_splash_screens/splash_screen_trans_rotate/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/android_views/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/channels/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/external_ui/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/flavors/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/flutter_driver_screenshot_test/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/flutter_gallery/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/hybrid_android_views/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/image_loading/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/ios_platform_view_tests/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/platform_interaction/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/release_smoke_test/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/ui/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/integration_tests/web_e2e_tests/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/snippets/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/tools/pubspec.yaml
git:    dev/tracing_tests/pubspec.yaml
git:    examples/hello_world/pubspec.yaml
git:    examples/platform_channel/pubspec.yaml
git:    examples/platform_channel_swift/pubspec.yaml
git:    packages/_flutter_web_build_script/pubspec.yaml
git:    packages/flutter_driver/pubspec.yaml
git:    packages/flutter_tools/pubspec.yaml
git:    packages/fuchsia_remote_debug_protocol/pubspec.yaml
git:    packages/integration_test/example/pubspec.yaml
git:    packages/integration_test/pubspec.yaml
git: Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
git: Aborting
Switching channels failed with error code 1.
```

How do I switch then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run these commands:

```dart
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
```